# How to check if in inside validtion request?

Tags: laravel, validation

I have this validation request:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id' =>  ['required', 'exists:users,id'],
        'address_type' =>  ['required', 'in:main_address,new_address'],
        'governorate_id' =>  ['required', 'exists:governorates,id'],
        'area_id' =>  ['required', 'exists:areas,id'],
        'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:15'],
        'nearly_area' => ['required', 'string', 'max:200'],
    ];
}
```

How can check if the user choose in `address_type (main_address one)` ignore the rest of fields and if `new_address` the rest fields should be required ??

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about but I think you are talking about this so here I share: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-required-if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `required_if` like:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'user_id' =>  ['required', 'exists:users,id'],
        'address_type' =>  ['required', 'in:main_address,new_address'],
        'governorate_id' =>  ['required_if:address_type,==,new_address', 'exists:governorates,id'],
        'area_id' =>  ['required_if:address_type,==,new_address', 'exists:areas,id'],
        'phone' => ['required_if:address_type,==,new_address', 'string', 'max:15'],
        'nearly_area' => ['required_if:address_type,==,new_address', 'string', 'max:200'],
    ];
}
```